# SORTING LISTS ...DONE! Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: linux, networking, ns2

I'm using ns2 and I want to write a tcl code for implementing wireless sensor networks, I surfed the net and I found a non complete code, I made some modifications to it and run it, but the terminal gives this result:

`channel.cc:sendUp - Calc highestAntennaZ_ and distCST_
highestAntennaZ_ = 1.5,  distCST_ = 550.0
SORTING LISTS ...DONE!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Actually, this is a project, so its okay if anyone can tell me the error in the code or give me a link for source code of implementing wireless sensor networks. 
This is my code. Thank you in advance.

```
set val(chan)           Channel/WirelessChannel    ;# channel type 
set val(prop)           Propagation/TwoRayGround   ;# radio-propagation model 
set val(netif)          Phy/WirelessPhy            ;# network interface type 
set val(mac)            Mac/802_11                 ;# MAC type 
set val(ifq)            Queue/DropTail/PriQueue    ;# interface queue type 
set val(ll)             LL                         ;# link layer type 
set val(ant)            Antenna/OmniAntenna        ;# antenna model 
set val(ifqlen)         50                         ;# max packet in ifq 
set val(nn)             3                         ;# number of mobilenodes 
set val(rp)             DSR                       ;# routing protocol 
set val(x)              1200               ;# X dimension of topography 
set val(y)              1000               ;# Y dimension of topography   
set val(stop)       50             ;# time of simulation end 
set val(err)        UniformErrorProc
# Set up topography object 
#------------------------------------------- 
set ns        [new Simulator] 
set tracefd       [open simple.tr w] 
set windowVsTime2 [open win.tr w]  
set namtrace      [open simwrls.nam w]  
# $ns use-newtrace 
$ns trace-all $tracefd 
$ns namtrace-all-wireless $namtrace $val(x) $val(y)

# set up topography object 
set topo [new Topography] 
$topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y) 
create-god $val(nn) 

proc UniformErrorProc {} { 
    puts "dfdfad-----------------------------"
    set err [new ErrorModel] 
    $err unit pkt 

    $err set rate_ 0.1 

    return $err 
}      

$ns node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
             -llType $val(ll) \
             -macType $val(mac) \
             -ifqType $val(ifq) \
             -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
             -antType $val(ant) \
             -propType $val(prop) \
             -phyType $val(netif) \
             -channel [new $val(chan)] \
             -topoInstance $topo \
             -agentTrace ON \
             -routerTrace OFF \
             -macTrace OFF \
             -movementTrace OFF \
             -IncomingErrProc $val(err)\
             -OutgoingErrProc $val(err)      

for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } { incr i } { 
    set node_($i) [$ns node]     
} 

$node_(0) set X_ 600.0 
$node_(0) set Y_ 500.0 
$node_(0) set Z_ 0.0 

$node_(1) set X_ 800.0 
$node_(1) set Y_ 400.0 
$node_(1) set Z_ 0.0 

$node_(2) set X_ 1000.0 
$node_(2) set Y_ 400.0 
$node_(2) set Z_ 0.0 

set tcp [new Agent/TCP/Newreno] 
$tcp set class_ 2
set sink [new Agent/TCPSink] 
$ns attach-agent $node_(0) $tcp 
$ns attach-agent $node_(2) $sink 
$ns connect $tcp $sink 

set ftp [new Application/FTP] 
$ftp attach-agent $tcp 
$ns at 1.0 "$ftp start" 

set udp [new Agent/UDP] 
$udp set class_ 2
set null [new Agent/Null] 
$ns attach-agent $node_(1) $udp
$ns attach-agent $node_(2) $null 
$ns connect $udp $null

set cbr_(0) [new Application/Traffic/CBR] 
$cbr_(0) set packetSize_ 200 
$cbr_(0) set interval_ 0.01 
$cbr_(0) set random_ 1 
$cbr_(0) set maxpkts_ 10000 
$cbr_(0) attach-agent $udp 
$ns at 11.0 "$cbr_(0) start"

# Printing the window size 
proc plotWindow {tcpSource file} { 
    global ns 
    set time 5.00 
    set now [$ns now] 
    set cwnd [$tcpSource set cwnd_] 
    puts $file "$now $cwnd"
    $ns at [expr $now+$time] "plotWindow $tcpSource $file" 
} 
    $ns at 10.1 "plotWindow $tcp $windowVsTime2"  

# Define node initial position in nam 
    for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn)} { incr i } {
# 30 defines the node size for nam 
    $ns initial_node_pos $node_($i) 30 
}

# Telling nodes when the simulation ends 
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } { incr i } { 
    $ns at $val(stop) "$node_($i) reset"; 
} 
proc stop {} { 
    global ns tracefd namtrace 
    $ns flush-trace
    close $tracefd 
    close $namtrace 
    exec nam out.nam & 
} 

$ns run
```

Comment: Run your code in a debugger, or add a bunch of print statements to know exactly where the code fails.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/  And nowhere in the code does it have "SORTING LISTS" in some kind of print statement, so I guess you have libraries or code we do not see in there?

Comment: Nic3500 : It's "ns2". Numerous OTcl text messages can appear. All built into the executable `ns`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

`$err set rate_` must be >= 1.0 :

```
30  proc UniformErrorProc {} { 
31      puts "dfdfad-----------------------------"
32      set err [new ErrorModel] 
33      $err unit pkt 
34  
35      $err set rate_ 1.0
36  
37      return $err
```

As is, the simulation will run for hours, and the three trace files can reach GB sizes. A "stop" can be added :

```
   13   set val(stop)       50000   ;# EDITED time of simulation end
   .
   .
   116  # Telling nodes when the simulation ends 
   117  for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } { incr i } { 
   118      $ns at $val(stop) "$node_($i) reset"; 
   119  }
   120   $ns at $val(stop).0002 "puts \"NS EXITING...\" ; $ns halt" ;# added
   121   $ns at $val(stop).0001 "stop"                              ;# added
   122  proc stop {} { 
   123      global ns tracefd namtrace 
   124      $ns flush-trace
   125      close $tracefd 
   126      close $namtrace 
   127      exec nam simwrls &           ;# edited
   128  } 
   129  
   130  $ns run
```

Run the simulation ...

```
$ ns235-64-orig s-WSN-Alibrahim.tcl
num_nodes is set 3
dfdfad-----------------------------
dfdfad-----------------------------
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead
dfdfad-----------------------------
dfdfad-----------------------------
dfdfad-----------------------------
dfdfad-----------------------------
channel.cc:sendUp - Calc highestAntennaZ_ and distCST_
highestAntennaZ_ = 1.5,  distCST_ = 550.0
SORTING LISTS ...DONE!
NS EXITING...
```

WSN examples, wsn-ex-11.17.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wd3r3QF3w2at44KsDxDDwQY-BxvfeqR0/view?usp=sharing ... All ~3000 simulations https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing